# Use laptop's keyboard shortcut in in Android device

Tags: genymotion

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 with Genymotion version 3.1.0 for my laptop. How do I use the laptop's keyboard shortcuts like Ctrl+C and Ctrl+V in the installed android device?

Answer (score 0):

Genymotion added support for copy and paste around their [2.1.0 version release](https://www.genymotion.com/product-release-note/desktop/).  The host device and virtual device share a clipboard so copy/paste is possible.

There are a few ways to copy/paste into an Android emulated device:

- long press on a text entry field and then choose "paste".
- `menu+c/menu+v` if your keyboard has this button.  [It looks like this.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menu_key#:%7E:text=In%20computing%2C%20the%20menu%20key,as%20the%20Windows%20logo%20key.)

  - Sometimes this is called the "application" key.  See: https://help.gnome.org/users/gnome-help/stable/keyboard-key-menu.html.en
- Change the IME to a keyboard that supports ctrl or alt for copy/paste.

I haven't used Genymotion in quite some time, but I would also try digging around its settings to see if there are key remapping options for things like copy/paste.

Comment: Thank you @CzarMatt. I tried the first suggestion and it's working. The second one doesn't work.